# get variable from url give error

Tags: php, get

I am using this code to get the variable iduser to use it in php as part of another url ( line2). But it gives me the following error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in" can you please show me my mistake.

```
 <?php  
 $iduser=$_GET['iduser'];
 $currsiteurl = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'$iduser;
```

Comment: you can also use: `"http://graph.facebook.com/$iduser"` note double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
   $iduser = $_GET['iduser'];
   $currsiteurl = "http://graph.facebook.com/${iduser}";
```

?>

should work hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error.

```
 $currsiteurl = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' . $iduser;
```

Comment: In PHP the `.` is user to concatenate two wtrings together. +1

Comment: I'll also add that `$currsiteurl = "http://graph.facebook.com/$iduser";` would have worked; but, if you're having syntax issues, I'd suggest you stick to the explicit concatenated form (the one I posted in the answer).

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the concatination `.` between string and variable:

```
$currsiteurl = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' . $iduser;
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
<?php  
 $iduser=$_GET['iduser'];
 $currsiteurl = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$iduser; 
?>
```

You have to use '.' to join string in php